# Keyboard shortcut problem/bug

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I don't know if it is a bug or a feature, but it is nevertheless annoying.

Let's say I change layer opacity and then click the layer just to deselect the "opacity box", if I now use the keyboard to pick a tool, say "E" for eraser, then Photoshop thinks I want to go to "Edit" in the top menu and so opens that drop-down all over my document. I must then click somewhere to close the menu and then try again, sometimes this doesn't work either.

Has anyone experienced this? Can you recreate it in your program?

EDIT:
As pointed out i forgot to state program version and OS. I have CS6 and Windows 8. I had a chance to test on CS5 on OSX and this did not occur, which leads me to believe it is a bug with CS6 and W8 or at least my computer.

Comment: Hi user14419, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Sounds like a Windows OS thing... You should ask Adobe for tech support issues.

Comment: Without the version of PS you're using, or which OS you're running it on, this can't truly be recreated.  My Photoshop (CS3) on Windows XP does not exhibit this behavior.  I know that simply clicking "Enter" will apply your opacity adjustment without the need for clicking a layer, and clicking "Esc" can get you out of menu navigation, FWIW.